# Clear Previous selection of Dropdown in EXCEL usingApache POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi, npoi

I have developed the excel using the Apache NPOI dll using HSSFWORKBOOK. But in my excel having 3 dependent dropdowns one in each other.

Here my question is I am unable to clear the cell value of dependent dropdowns. Let say like dropdown1 have country values and on the selection of this dropdown2 state values got a filter and selected one of the state. Now if I changed the country again able to filter the data but whatever the previous state selection not getting cleared.

[image: Here is the Sample that dropdown 2 and 3 are not cleared if i changed the dropdown1 value.]

code ref:

No, i am just referring the list of columns data from sheet2 to sheet1 using the formulae.  below is code ref:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //if (i >= MaxRowCount)
                    //{
                    //    sheet2.CreateRow(1000 + i).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
                    //    MaxRowCount += 1;
                    //}
                    //else
                    //    sheet2.GetRow(1000 + i).CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());

                    if (CategoryCount == 250)
                    {
                        rownumber = rownumber + 3000;
                        CategoryCount = 16;
                        MaxRowCount = 0;

                    }

                    DataRow[] DR = ds.Tables[1].Select("LOCATION_ID=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                    int RowCount = 0;

                    //int rownumber = 1000;
                    foreach (DataRow d in DR)
                    {

                        if (RowCount >= MaxRowCount)
                        {
                            sheet2.CreateRow(rownumber + RowCount).CreateCell(CategoryCount).SetCellValue(d[0].ToString());
                            MaxRowCount += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sheet2.GetRow(rownumber + RowCount).CreateCell(CategoryCount).SetCellValue(d[0].ToString());
                        }
                        RowCount++;
                    }





IName DeptHierarchy_Dept = hssfworkbook.CreateName();
                            DeptHierarchy_Dept.NameName = "XDeptHierarchy_Dept_SUB" + (XDeptHierarchy_Dept_SUBCount).ToString();
                            if (CategoryCount / 26 < 1)
                                DeptHierarchy_Dept.RefersToFormula = "'Template Field Specs2'!$" + ((char)(65 + CategoryCount)).ToString() + "$" + (StartRowNumber + 1) + ":$" + ((char)(65 + CategoryCount)).ToString() + "$" + ((StartRowNumber + 1) + (RowCount == 0 ? 0 : RowCount - 1)).ToString();
                            else
                                DeptHierarchy_Dept.RefersToFormula = "'Template Field Specs2'!$" + ((char)(65 + (CategoryCount / 26) - 1)).ToString() + ((char)(65 + CategoryCount % 26)).ToString() + "$" + (StartRowNumber + 1) + ":$" + ((char)(65 + (CategoryCount / 26) - 1)).ToString() + ((char)(65 + CategoryCount % 26)).ToString() + "$" + ((StartRowNumber + 1) + (RowCount == 0 ? 0 : RowCount - 1)).ToString();
                            CategoryCount++;
                            XDeptHierarchy_Dept_SUBCount++;
```

Comment: are you setting the value using row.Cells[header].SetCellValue("state");  on country change? Please share your code snippet.

Comment: No, i am just referring the list of columns data from sheet2 to sheet1 using the formulae. pls See the code ref above.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "Dependent Drop Down Lists". You'll have to be creative for your formula because your row will keep changing.
one approach i can think of is store the list of "Country-capital" on named region some where deep in excel. On selection of country, parse and find the capital from named region and populate your target cell.
Please see the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).
Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113804/how-to-create-dependent-drop-downs-in-excel-sheet-generated-using-poi);